# How to handle exception when web service is not available in java

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

I need to handle an exception when web service is not available. In my app i am requesting an web service what will return me an XML data. My app is working correctly when web service is available. But when the web service is unavailable then my app become crash.how to catch that exception in java. Please note that i am developing an app for android.

when the web service is unavailable the it looks likes the following image
[image]

Comment: check the response code what for your case and add a check for that response code. You may need to take different actions for different response codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this you can check webservice available or not

```
public void isAvailable(){

    // first check if there is a WiFi/data connection available... then:

    URL url = new URL("URL HERE");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(10000); // Timeout 10 seconds
    connection.connect();

    // If the web service is available
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: In a real multi-threaded environment, the resource may become unavailable right after the check was made (so the check passes), but before the actual request is made (so the call fails). It's the same common mistake that people do with files - check if exists, then do some action, without catching exception for the action itself. Considering this scenario, the above code isn't very helpful for production use.

Comment: of-course i agree, it is just an beginner level code, not for production .. response code can be modified added by any coder by him/herself, you can modify my answer as you wish for experienced coders

Answer (score 1):

This is how i have solved that problem with the help of [Krishna's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141278/krishna) code

```
public static boolean isAvailable(String link){

        boolean available = false; 

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(link);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        } catch (IOException e1) {

        }
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(100000); // Timeout 100 seconds
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

        try {
            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
             //   return true;
                available = true;
            }
            else 
                available = false;
                //return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return available;
}
```